# How can Combat Expertise gained from the Passive Way fighting style be replaced?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, class-feature, fighting-style

I took 2 levels of monk for mainly to get at level 2 the alternative class feature **invisible fist** and the feat **Improved Trip** as a bonus feat from the monk fighting style Passive Way. However, at level 1 the monk fighting style Passive Way gave me the all but useless feat **Combat Expertise**.

Is there a way to replace the feat Combat Expertise with another feat? I know becoming a dragonborn allows replacing a feat with a Draconic feat, but the DM won't allow my PC to become one.

Is there another method of changing the Combat Expertise bonus feat to another feat?

---

*Note: Official* 3.5 *material only.* Dragon *and other magazines are unacceptable. All other material is allowed except, for story reasons, the dragonborn.*

Comment: *"my DM does not let me"* - what material your DM will actually let you use? What he agreed to? Without that info, providing answers you will actually be able to use is next to impossible. Are all templates off limits? What publications, in addition to Dragon Magazine he banned? And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You may not have to if the DM'll let you retcon just a little

*Unearthed Arcana* on [**Monk Variant: Fighting Styles**](http://dndsrd.net/unearthedCoreClass.html#fighting-styles), in part, says

> A monk can abandon her fighting style by selecting a different bonus feat at 2nd or 6th level; however, if she does so, she loses the bonus on skill checks gained at 1st level and never gains the bonus ability of the fighting style (even if she meets
>   the prerequisites). (52)

In other words, at level 1 the monk could've avoided the Combat Expertise feat by taking a bonus feat from a fighting style other than Passive way (like the Overwhelming Attack fighting style that at level 1 grants the bonus feat Power Attack). Then, at level 2, the monk could've gained the feat Improved Trip from the fighting style Passive Way. All that such a multi-styled monk gives up at level 2 is a +2 bonus on a specific skill. (The fighting style Passive Way, for example, grants a +2 bonus on Bluff skill checks.)

The rule's kind of buried, phrased poorly, and easily overlooked. Explaining to the DM that you were unaware of the rule might be enough for the DM to allow you to change the feat without the need for in-game explanation.

---

***Note:*** This answer isn't meant as a comprehensive solution to the broader issues the question raises but is instead an effort to address the asker's specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers offer some options, but I'd like to offer another option.
Bear in mind that the below uses content from *Fiendish Codex I* and is to some considered cheese....

**Dark Chaos Shuffle**

This is considered a pretty simple way of getting rid of feats gained from class features or other sources that are unwanted.

The first is to find someone who can cast the *Embrace the Dark Chaos* spell on you, which has the following benefit:

> The subject immediately gains one Abyssal heritor feat for which it qualifies, chosen by you at the time of casting.
>   If the subject does not qualify for the designated feat, the spell fails.
>   **This Abyssal heritor feat replaces one feat of the subject's choice that it already possesses.**
>   The replaced feat need not have been an Abyssal heritor feat.... ....Once the subject has the Abyssal heritor feat, only a miracle,
>   shun the dark chaos, or wish spell can reverse the change.

Which sounds like it doesn't really help because I'm guessing you are not looking to replace it with an Abyssal Heritor feat. That's where *Shun the Dark Chaos* comes in:

> If the subject possesses any Abyssal heritor feats, one of them is immediately removed and replaced by any other feat for which the subject qualifies (except an Abyssal heritor feat).
>   **The subject chooses both the feat lost and its replacement**.

This allows us to replace an Abyssal Heritor feat(like the one gained from *Embrace the Dark Chaos*) and replace it with ANY OTHER FEAT.

Combining the two: We go from wasted feat to wasted Abyssal feat to finally actually helpful feat that we select.